# join list of lists the proper way

Tags: python

I don't know if I am stupid but I have a small issue. I have a list `list1` of lists. Like you can see below the list items in this list are ints. In a simple for loop I can loop through all these lists. So this:

```
list1 = [ [0, 1], [2], [3], [4,5,6,7], [8,9], [10], [11,12], ...... ]
for item in list1:
    print item
```

will yield:

```
[0, 1]
[2]
[3]
[4,5,6,7]
...
```

Lets say we are at the first iteration. The `item` is `[0, 1]`. What I'm looking for is a one-line code that gives me access to `0` and `1` because I want to print a line later on that looks like "This is 0 and 1". Sounds easy right? I thought I just `join` every `item`:

```
list1 = [ [0, 1], [2], [3], [4,5,6,7], [8,9], [10], [11,12], ...... ]

for item in list1:
    print [x for x in ''.join(item) ]
```

gives this error:

```
print [x for x in ''.join(item) ]
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, int found
```

I just can't join `[0, 1]` because python want me to use strings. If I cast `item` to string with this line:

```
print [x for x in ''.join(str(item)) ]
```

I get this ugly result:

```
['[', '0', ',', ' ', '1', ']']
```

Can anyone please tell me how to proper do this? I'm feeling a little bit stupid right now. Like I said before I would like to write something like `'This is '.join(str(item))` (one line code)

Comment: Do you understand .join(item) and why it has single quotes before it.

Comment: can you explain what output you want to get?

Comment: something like that: 0.txt 1.txt 2.txt ... Seems like "map" is the key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of converting the whole sublist to a string, you need to convert each item in each sublist to a string before joining, e.g.

```
>>> list1 = [ [0, 1], [2], [3], [4,5,6,7], [8,9], [10], [11,12] ]
>>> for sublist in list1:
...     print ' '.join(map(str, sublist))
... 
0 1
2
3
4 5 6 7
8 9
10
11 12
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you just want, e.g.:

```
for item in list1:
    print " ".join(map(str, item))
```

In Python 3.x, you can do:

```
for item in list1:
    print(*item)
```

Answer (score 1):

> I want to print a line later on that looks like "This is 0 and 1".

```
list1 = [ [0, 1], [2], [3], [4,5,6,7], [8,9], [10], [11,12] ]

for item in list1:
    print ('This is {}.'.format(' and '.join(str(x) for x in item)))
```