# concatenate strings based on ints from a list

Tags: python

I had a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20908669/join-list-of-lists-the-proper-way) but it's a different issue. I have two lists. list0 is a list of strings and list1 is a list of lists consisting of ints.

```
        # In this example are 8 strings
list0 = ["Test", "Test2", "More text", "Test123", "ttt", "abc", "okokok", "Hello"]
list1 = [ [0, 1], [2], [3], [4,5,6], [7] ...... ]
        # therefore 8 ints, 0 - 7; it always starts with 0.
```

There are exact the same number of strings in `list0` as ints in `list1`.

I want to loop through the items of list1 (`[0,1], [2], ...`) and concatenate the strings from list0 according to the int numbers of the item from `list1`. So `new_list[0]+new_list[1]` should beconcatenated, 2 and 3 not, than 4+5+6 should be concatenated and so on... I don't know how to do that in one single for loop since the amount of ints in one item can vary. So what I am looking for is a new concatenated list that should look like this:

```
           # 0 and 1         2           3        4  5  6          7
new_list = ["TestTest", "More text", "Test123", "tttabcokokok", "Hello"]
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use list comprehensions and `str.join()`:

```
new_list = [''.join([list0[i] for i in indices]) for indices in list1]
```

Demo:

```
>>> list0 = ["Test", "Test2", "More text", "Test123", "ttt", "abc", "okokok", "Hello"]
>>> list1 = [ [0, 1], [2], [3], [4,5,6], [7]]
>>> [''.join([list0[i] for i in indices]) for indices in list1]
['TestTest2', 'More text', 'Test123', 'tttabcokokok', 'Hello']
```

Comment: I swear there is always a 1-line solution in Python. I just never know what it is :)

Answer (score 4):

I'd go for `operator.itemgetter` and a list-comp*, eg:

```
from operator import itemgetter

list0 = ["Test", "Test2", "More text", "Test123", "ttt", "abc", "okokok", "Hello"]
list1 = [ [0, 1], [2], [3], [4,5,6], [7] ]

new = [''.join(itemgetter(*indices)(list0)) for indices in list1]
# ['TestTest2', 'More text', 'Test123', 'tttabcokokok', 'Hello']
```

<sub>* Well - no I'd go for the list-comp - it's faster and doesn't require an import... Consider this an alternative though...</sub>

Comment: Thanks for teaching me about [itemgetter](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter)!